# Can I pass a long bash command to asyncio.subprocess.create_subprocess_exec()?

Tags: python-3.x, subprocess, python-asyncio

Right off the bat, there is a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38730288/unable-use-bash-commands-through-asyncio?s=3|0.0539) but it doesn't quite answer *my* question. I left a comment there just in case though.

In `asyncio` there is a `asyncio.subprocess.create_subprocess_exec` coroutine mimicking the more common `subprocess.Popen` command with `shell=False` to protect against shell injection. `Popen` accepts a *list* of strings but `create_subprocess_exec` only accepts strings, like

```
asyncio.subprocess.create_subprocess_exec('ls', '-lah', 'myfile', stdout=..., stderr=..., stdin=...)
```

I have a bash command as a big string, e.g. `s = 'ls -lah myfile'`. I want to pass the command to `create_subprocess_exec` *but a list like `s.split()` doesn't work!* How do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems that `asyncio.subprocess.create_subprocess_exec` will accept a starred list as a series of arguments, so the solution should be

```
cmd = ['ls', '-lah', 'myfile']
asyncio.subprocess.create_subprocess_exec(*cmd, stdout=asyncio.subprocess.PIPE, stderr=asyncio.subprocess.PIPE, stdin=asyncio.subprocess.PIPE)
```

A word of caution, formatting bash commands in this way can be difficult, especially with `rsync` I'm finding.

Comment: What if the argument list/single argument is so long that the command line can't accommodate it ? What would you suggest for such a scenario ?